# ZOOM Api is reporting incorrect participant data

Tags: zoom-sdk

We are encountering an issue with the Zoom API for fetching participants.

Most of the time, the API only returns a subset of the list. However, when we log in and download the list from a host's account, we are able to retrieve the entire list.

For reference, we have used both of the following APIs to fetch the participant list without much success:

- `/report/meetings/{meetingId}/participants`
- `/past_meetings/{meetingUUID}/participants`